# Groupby and Sum without pandas for CSV values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

here is the given data format

```
USERID, USERNAME, EVENTID, DATE, AMOUNT
001,User1,EV-001,2020-01-01,1000
E001,User1,EV-001,2021-01-01,1000
E001,User1,EV-002,2020-03-01,300
E001,User1,EV-002,2020-04-01,500
E002,User2,EV-003,2020-01-02,100
E002,User2,EV-003,2020-02-02,200
E002,User3,EV-003,2020-03-02,300
E003,User4,EV-004,2024-01-01,100
```

If i am suppose to sum the column 4 for each EVENTID before  for SORTED BY USERID, how to i group them.

I tried this for every row in csv to create a list of dict with EVENTID as key and other columns as list for value. Then summed over the list for each key, but then that gives me the summation per EVENTID and i am not able to find a way to group them(per USERID) before summing

```html
if (row['DATE'] <= input_date):
    vesting_by_award[row['AWARD_ID']].append(
                    {'USERID': row['USERID'], 'USERNAME': 
// i do above for every row

row['USERNAME'], 'AMOUNT': row['AMOUNT']})        
    for k, v in vesting_by_award.items():
                # print(list(v))
                result[k] = {'SUM': sum(
                    int(item['AMOUNT'])for item in list(v))}
```

input_date : 2020-04-01

output : {'EV001': {'SUM': 1000}, 'EV002': {'SUM': 800}, 'EV003': {'SUM': 600}})

desired_output :

```
E001,User1,EV-001,1000
E001,User1,EV-002,800
E002,User2,EV-001,600
E003,User3,EV-003,0
```

The intention is to do this without using pandas.

Comment: Why don’t you want to use pandas? It would be very easy, and the best tool for the job, I think

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to do. Your dictionary/hash table approach would be the way to do this when not using pandas but you need to reorganize your dictionary.

Assuming you are trying to sum(AMOUNT) for each EVENTID for each USERID then you need to have the dictionary setup with USERID as the first key, EVENTID as the second key, and the AMOUNTs as the final value.

If "row" is a tuple or list and "rows" is a list of row tuples/lists:

```
for row in rows:
    try:
        my_dict[row[0]][row[2]].append(row[-1])
    except KeyError:
        my_dict[row[0]][row[2]] = [row[-1]]
```

Then you can compute sums. If this is not what you're trying to do, the logic still holds. Main concept is to create your dictionary with the proper hierarchical structure.

Not sure why you do not want to use pandas but that is probably the right tool for the job in this case.

Comment: I am Entering into a structure which looks like

 ['1000', 'USER1, '2020-01-01', ['1000', 'USER1', '2021-01-01']]

WHEN i use
          result = []
          temp_list = [
                     row['AMOUNT'], row['USERNAME'], row['DATE']]
        if row['EVENTID'] not in result:
            result[row['EVENTID']] = [temp_list]
        else:
            result[row['EVENTID']].append(temp_list)

Comment: Okay, from your original question and desired output, it sounds like you are trying get the sum of amounts grouped by userID and eventID. Is this correct? You do not seem to need/use username and if you do need it you should be able to map userID to username so it does not need to be part of your grouping. The code you're showing in your comment shows result as a list, not a dict. The result you showed above seems redundant. I'd like to help more but this does not seem like the correct way to do this. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do without code? also why you can't use pandas?